# C*-algebra generated by two normal operators

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be two distinct commuting normal elements. $C*$-algebra generated by $N_1$ and $N_2$ is a commutative $C*$-algebra. So, it will be of the form $C(X)$ for $X$ some compact set in a topological space.

> Is $X$ of the form $\sigma(N_1) \times \sigma(N_2)$?

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

I have mentioned two distinct normal elements after Polp's comment.

Comment: If $N_1 = N_2$, most certainly not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have added two distinct normal elements in the question.

Comment: It probably isn't enough. Let $A$ be a normal element. Then $A^2$ commutes with $A$, is normal too, is distinct from $A$ in general; however, the algebra generated by $A$ and the algebra generated by $\{A,A^2\}$ are the same.

Comment: As suggested by Plop's comments, this is a matter of "independence". It is necessary and sufficient that the only relations of the form $f(N_1,N_2)=0$ with $f$ continuous between $N_1$ and $N_2$ are the ones with $f=0$ on $\sigma(N_1)\times\sigma(N_2)$. Of course, if you express it in this way, the statement is almost tautological.

Comment: @Plop Okay. But I was looking for some characterization C*-algebra generated by two commuting operator. Is there any result on that?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the case in general, even if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are distinct and differ from the identity. For example, let $N_1$ be a normal operator on a finite dimensional space with two distinct eigenvalues and let $N_2$ denote the spectral projection associated with one of them. Note that $N_2 \in C^*(N_1)$ and so $$C^*(N_1, N_2) = C^*(N_1) \cong C(\sigma(N_1)).$$
However, $\sigma(N_2) = \{0,1 \}$. Thus, the dimension of $C(\sigma(N_1) \times \sigma(N_2))$ is double that of $C(\sigma(N_1))$.